# Twitter Elephant Bird Installation

Tags: installation, protocol-buffers, centos7, elephantbird

I am trying to install twitter's Elephant Bird parser and I am following the instructions on the official github page. But everytime, the build fails. I am not even sure if I am doing it right because I everytime I build, I have aan error that says:

```
Failed to execute goal com.github.igor-petruk.protobuf:protobuf-maven-plugin:0.6.5:run (default) on project elephant-bird-core: 'protoc' failed
```

I am really confused on how to install protobufs. It has different languages and I am not sure which language I need to choose. It says something like dynamic installation. 3 days of work yielded nothing.

Can some one please walk me through ALL the installation steps (with installation procedure for prerequisites as well). Please understand I am too naive and new to linux. Really appreciate the help.

I am using centos 7.

EDIT:

1. I used this [link](https://leveragebigdata.wordpress.com/2015/10/08/install-protocol-buffer-2-5-0/) to install protobuf 2.4.1.
2. `mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true package` inside elephant-bird directory.

I get:

```
[INFO] Building Elephant Bird Pig 4.15-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Elephant Bird ..................................... SUCCESS [0.304s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Hadoop Compatibility ................ SUCCESS [0.598s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Core ................................ SUCCESS [2.513s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Cascading2 .......................... SUCCESS [0.042s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Cascading3 .......................... SUCCESS [0.034s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Cascading Protobuf .................. SUCCESS [0.024s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Crunch .............................. SUCCESS [0.101s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Hive ................................ SUCCESS [0.114s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Pig ................................. FAILURE [0.045s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Mahout .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Elephant Bird RCFile .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Elephant Bird Lucene .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Elephant Bird Pig Lucene .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Elephant Bird Examples ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------------- ---
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] Total time: 4.104s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Oct 17 13:43:13 EDT 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 24M/750M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project elephant-bird-pig: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.twitter.elephantbird:elephant-bird-pig:jar:4.15-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.twitter.elephantbird:elephant-bird-core:jar:tests:4.15-SNAPSHOT in http://maven.twttr.com was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of twitter has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

I don't know what to do. Can someone help me?

Comment: Were you able to build?

Comment: @NishantKumar No, I just downloaded the jars from the maven repository.

Comment: Did it work after that?